# PhpStorm 2023: How to disable all Git operations?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Working with PHP in PhpStorm 2023, from time to time I get messages that some git operation was run (I suppose by accidentally clicking some hot key).

I search for some option to disable all git operations but failed to find such an option:

[image]

Does PhpStorm have such an option ?

Comment: Git is a bundled plugin, I presume you can disable it altogether if you don't really use Git. If you actually use it, it seems too drastic to get rid of it entirely.

Comment: I did not find any "git" plugin installed  under Menu=>Settings=>Plugins. Which is the name of the plugin ?

Comment: Literally, "Git": https://i.imgur.com/uAt5cwd.png